# Is there any function to get all sub-collection in a specific collection?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I have collections A and B. A and B have sub-collections with the same name as C. I would like to get all sub-collections C in collection A.

For using `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('C').get()` will get all sub-collections C in collection A and B.

For using this, below must get big data before receiving sub-collection.

```
  CollectionReference collectionData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('A');
  collectionData.get().then((value) {
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc in value.docs) {
      collectionData
          .doc(doc.id)
          .collection('C')
          .get()
          .then((value) {});
    }
  });
```

Is there any function to get all sub-collection in a specific collection like `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('A').collectionGroup('C').get()`?

Comment: You may be interested by this article: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166

Comment: I have seen `db.collection("restaurants").doc("123").collection("reviews").get()` before but this method can't get all documents. This must use `.doc("required key")`. Where did I miss?

Comment: CollectionReference collectionData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection( 'A/{subCollectionName}         ');
  collectionData.get().then((value) {
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc in value.docs) {
      collectionData
          .doc(doc.id)
          .collection('C')
          .get()
          .then((value) {});
    }
  });






You can use above syntax to get the inner or sub collection

Comment: Hi @KurbanAliMasu, ,CollectionReference collectionData = `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection( 'A/{subCollectionName} '); ` give error `"a collection path must point to a valid collection."`